# How to sample groups by a condition a subset of each group's data should satisfy using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there is a better way to solve the following problem.

I have a dataset that tracks the price of products over time (using a relative time index centered around some event date (t=0)):*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 
                   'time': [-2,-1,0,1,2,-2,-1,0,1,2],
                   'price': [1,2,3,4,5,1,4,3,2,1]})
```

I want to sample all products where the prices before the event (t<0) are lower (<) than the price at the event (t=0).

For `df`, I should only sample product 1 (because for product 2: price t=-1 > price t=0):

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1], 
              'time': [-2,-1,0,1,2],
              'price': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

**In my current implementation**, I create a column with the `event price` (price at t=0) and find all `id`s where all `price` < `event price`  for `time`<0, and then sample using the `id`s. I feel like this should be solvable with `groupby`, but don't know how get each `id`s price at t=0 for the condition.

---

/* all products have the same time window. That is, in this example, all products have a relative time window from -2 to 2. The window is always symmetric around 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. You can create the event price column in your DF by joining a new DF that has the event price per id then do some simple filtering.

```py
df = df.merge(
    df.loc[df.time == 0, ['id', 'price']],
    on='id',
    suffixes=('', '_event')
)
df = df.loc[
    # exclude ids where prices at times t < 0 are not all less than price at t = 0
    ~df.id.isin(
        df.loc[
            (df.time < 0) &
            (df.price >= df.price_event),
            'id'
        ].values
    ),
    ['id', 'time', 'price']
]
df
```

Output:

```
   id time price
0   1   -2     1
1   1   -1     2
2   1    0     3
3   1    1     4
4   1    2     5
```

Comment: thanks! the output isn't correct though (see output I provided above). I want to sample *products* that satisfy the condition for all observations (t<0), not just observations where the condition is met. The result should not include any data from product 2, but should include all data for product 1.

Comment: maybe to make it clearer. I could take your filter and merge it again with the dataset:
`df = df.merge(df.loc[(df.time < 0) & (df.price < df.price_event)].groupby('id')['price_event'].count().rename('n'), on='id')`
and then filter on `n`: `df.loc[df.n == 2, ['id', 'time', 'price']]`, which would give me my desired output. This is equivalent to my approach, but seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @greyBag Can you explain what you mean by "sample"?

Comment: @greyBag Your questions says "I want to sample all products where the prices before the event (t<0) are lower (<) than the price at the event (t=0)." Are you wanting to identify rows where t < 0 and its price < price for that id at t = 0 or are you wanting to identify rows for an id where ALL rows t < 0 have a price < price for that id at t = 0?

Comment: its closer to the second one. I want to select the all the rows belonging to an id (t=[-2, 1, 0, 1, 2]), where all rows t<0 have a price<price@t=0 for that id.

Comment: @greyBag Oh gotcha. I'll edit my answer.